# What do Disease Broodoo Victims deal damage with?

Tags: runescape

Can a Disease Broodoo victim cause disease effects? There is a Relyic's Balm that cures disease but when and where is that potion necessary? Is it to protect myself or just to kill the victim?

Answer (score 2):

Each colored Broodoo Victim is weak to something.

The yellow ones are weak to [Relicym's Balm](https://runescape.wiki/w/Relicym%27s_balm) that you mention. So it is just meant to kill these guys rather than protect you.

The white ones are weak to food easiest being [Cooked Meat](https://runescape.wiki/w/Cooked_meat) bought from the general store but MANY other options available.  Basically any food item.

The green ones are weak to [Antipoison](https://runescape.wiki/w/Antipoison).

Here is the wiki page that describes them all in full depth: [Broodoo Victims](https://runescape.wiki/w/Broodoo_victim)

Comment: I don't use cooked meat. A sack of cabbages yields 10 food per inv. space and has the same effect.

Comment: Yeah that is probably an easier method I just went with the most accessible from that area so i wouldn't have to go Bank.

Comment: OK, 2 years later this is yet not chosen as an answer :) I think it should be

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev Haha I know right?  But the user doesn't look active anymore so I feel it will probably stay this way.  But remember they knew how the system works...